# Loading Australian Electoral Commission data (MIF/MID) into QGIS for Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, australia, mif

I have installed QGIS for Ubuntu (linux) and downloaded some GIS electoral data from the AEC.  When I try to open the files (they have MID and MIF extensions), the application does not recognise the files.  What can I do to open these files in QGIS?

Comment: Perhaps search the help for MapInfo because that is the software that created that data.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS can read MapInfo files. Drag & Drop the MID / MIF files onto the Map Canvas. If you try to open it by `Project | Open` it will not work.

Comment: @StuartAnderson Great! I myself just learned d&d trick a few days ago. :)